# Build a project in Release mode quickly without switching from Debug mode to Release mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In my work, I usually use Debug mode to run my projects and I also want to debug them as needed. Sometimes, I also want to deploy one project DLL to production. I must switch from Debug to Release mode on my solution and build it again. After completing, I re-switch from Release to Debug mode to come back my work.

I need the fastest way or have a option to build Release on my selected project while my solution is still in Debug mode.

I'm using VS 2010 & C#.

Comment: Doing a [Batch Build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980429/how-to-build-debug-and-release-at-once?rq=1) or using MSBUILD (i.e. no GUI) might help?

Comment: See also [Visual Studio: Keyboard shortcut to switch between Debug and Release modes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033953/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-debug-and-release-modes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there is a direct shortcut for something like that. But you can do:

```
Alt + B , O, R, Enter
F6
Alt + B, O, D, Enter
```

It is actually opening options from the menu as under:

```
Alt + B -> Build Menu
O -> Configuration Manager
R -> To Select Release Mode
Enter -> To close the Configuration Manager

F6 -> Build
Alt + B -> Build Menu
O -> Configuration Manager
D -> To Select Debug Mode
Enter -> To close the Configuration Manager
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a Tools menu entry to Visual Studio using devenv.exe with the command line params of '$(SolutionDir)$(SolutionFileName) /build Release' in the arguments field to send in the currently open solution and configuration mode as parameters to a new command line instance of devenv.exe. This can be done via the Tools menu, External Tools item inside of Visual Studio. This would not require you to change the build configuration in the open solution and you could assign a menu shortcut key to the item.

IE:

devenv c:\temp\solution.sln /build Release

You may wish to also take a look at the other devenv paramters by doing a 'devenv /?' at the prompt. Also, if you have the solution open in Visual Studio, make sure your source files are saved before issuing the build.