# Command to switch between debug and release in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is there a command that allows me to change the build configuration easily (e.g., Debug or Release) in Visual Studio?

I see the function in the toolbar, but I try to work only with commands if possible. For commands I can easily define aliases and use parameters for direct switching to a known build configuration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard shortcut to switch between Debug and Release modes in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033953/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-debug-and-release-modes-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Yes and no. Keyboard shortcuts could be a workaround for me. But, using a command is more comfortable to remind and more flexible. For commands, I can often use parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link [Keyboard shortcut to switch between Debug and Release modes in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033953/) from user3399 provided the right direction: 
If I enter in the command window the first characters from a menu, in my case **Erstellen**, I get code completion, and I tried some commands. In my case

`Erstellen.Projektmappenkonfigurationen Release`

works like expected. I add an additional alias, and now it's simpler to use:

```
alias pc Erstellen.Projektmappenkonfigurationen
pc Debug
```

If somebody can write the English command, I will edit/update my answer for better finding for other users.

Comment: Jeez, they start translating everything to German again? I thought we already went through this with VBA

Answer (score 1):

In English the command name is **Build.SolutionConfigurations**.

And with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension you can create a direct command to switch a configuration like this:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.SolutionConfigurations", "Debug");
```