# How to Call Custom function in visual studio ide extension customization?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

i know i can extend visual studio 2019 via tools>customize as shown here:

[image]

i just need to create a class and function in it and instead of running exisiting functions, just run my own functions. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to create a class and function and call it from the VCmd menu in Visual Studio.

Comment: thanks for amazing tool ypu made but i wantt to change project settings in editor. many of settings are available as : configuration.Properties.Item("DefineConstants").Value; but there is no way to change Between Debug and Release in my project settings. is there any programatical method for it?

Comment: @user2921883 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58911590/command-to-switch-between-debug-and-release-in-visual-studio